# .net ReportViewer javascript error

Tags: javascript, .net, user-controls, reportviewer

I am using the ReportViewer (2012, version 11) user control in a webform that is loaded into iframe on a MVC single page app.  I find that I run one report and it works fine, but then I go to another report It won't run till I refresh.

The previous content section with the iframe has been removed from the dom so I don't see how it would be interfering with the next report.  my guess is that the report viewer pollutes the hell out of the global namespace.

In anycase the error is

```
TypeError: cs is null
return cs.getPropertyValue('direction');
```

Does anyone know about this or if there is a way to clean up after the reportviewer or if there is a better reportviewer control?

Comment: Not helpful I'm afraid but I've had so many problems with the stock report viewer that I now avoid it - it gets even worse if you're using entities and repositories as it doesn't support lambdas (at least not in 2010, last time I checked). Good luck though

Comment: @Basic is there any alternative to it?  Some opensource thing maybe.  There's no denying that it's a POS

Comment: in the end we went with the Telerik report viewer. Not free (~$600/user I think) but it was worth the saving in dev time getting anything else working. It's pretty damned good but may not be what you're after. Unfortunately, I haven't found a decent OS alternative (but let me know if you come across one)

Answer (score 0):

My application is similar to yours. I'm using jQuery to load the ReportViewer into a DOM element (embedded in an iframe).

Something similar to this:

```
var formargs = $("#reportArgsForm").serialize();
var windowheight = $("#content").height() - 8;
var link = '<iframe id="report_iframe" style="height:' + windowheight + 'px;width:99%;overflow: visible;" src="Reports/SimpleReportViewer.aspx?' + formargs + '"></iframe>';

$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 1);
$("#tabs-display").html(link);
```

If you notice, the report is actually displayed within it's own jQuery-UI tab. I ran into the same error because I had upgraded to jQuery-UI 1.10.1 and the tabs ["select" method wasn't working any more](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-select-method).

In my case the error was buried deep within Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient._InternalReportViewer.GetRTLDirection. The report viewer code was trying to call window.getComputedStyle on some element and it was returning null. It was null because the element being passed in wasn't visible.

Once I fixed the jQuery-UI tab switching issue, the ReportViewer error ("cs is null") went away.